# BigCommerce Custom Add To Cart Speed Issue

Tags: bigcommerce

We had a developer add a custom code to certain product pages so that the user could order multiple quantities of multiple product variants all at once from one product page.

The issue is that the script takes too long to run...when you click Add To Cart it is taking 30-60 seconds or more to add all the products to the cart.

That is way too long. **([see video here](https://www.dipietro.biz/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/add-to-cart-slow.webm) https://www.dipietro.biz/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/add-to-cart-slow.webm )**

This is because the script is adding each product to the cart sequentially one by one instead of simultaneously.

Is this something that can be fixed?

We need the Add To Cart speed increased drastically.

I've been told that if we had access to the cart.php file that sits on BigCommerce's server we could just add some type of ajax multi array function and that would solve the problem but of course we do not have access to BigCommerce's servers.

Any help is appreciated at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: @alyss a colleague mentioned that you're an expert w/ BigCommerce and may be able to help with this?

Comment: After looking at the store/script, the first thing I'd start with is separating the rangeboxSelect() function and multiaddFun() function. Rangeboxselect currently contains multiaddfun(). You can also time your javascript to see the slowest parts by adding something like console.time (https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2013/11/22/measuring-execution-times-in-javascript-with-consoletime)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, most likely the issue is that, as you mentioned, the products are being added to the cart sequentially, while also waiting for each individual *add to cart* request to finish before beginning the next - that is, it will add a product to the cart, wait for that product to successfully be added, and then proceed to add the next product to the cart.

Each *'add to cart'* action is an individual *POST* request to the `cart.php` file. There is a challenge here in that BigCommerce will block the requests if too many of them occur within a certain time period; this is a BigCommerce security feature.

While you do not have access to the `cart.php` file, and while I do not know the specifics of the BigCommerce rate-limit/security feature, the best way to approach this is to determine and set a feasible max number of concurrent requests as well as a necessary *cool-down* period in order to maximize the number of requests to BigCommerce while also satisfying the security/rate-limit limitation.

For example, you might set up the program to concurrently add 3 products to the cart, wait 1 second, and then proceed to add another 3 products. Does this make sense?